# Need to navigate to next element in an array in Polymer on button click

Tags: polymer

I have an array of objects that contain emp info like name age etc and I have a page with previous and next buttons. I want to be able to navigate to the object in the array after clicking on the next button. Do I need use something like redux to achieve this or is there another way to do this. Is there a way to do this in polymer directly.

```
<dom-module id="my-quiz">
    <template>
        <div>Employee List</div>
            <button on-click="prev">Previous</button>
            <button on-click="next">Next</button>
    </template>
    <script>
        class Quiz extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'my-quiz'; }

            // set this element's employees property
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.employees = [
                    { name: 'Bob', id: 'b1' },
                    { name: 'Ayesha', id: 'b2' },
                    { name: 'Fatma', id: 'b3' },
                    { name: 'Tony', id: 'b5' }
                ];
            }

            prev() {
                console.log("prev");
            }

            next() {
                console.log("next");
            }

        }
        window.customElements.define(Quiz.is, Quiz);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example how to do this. There may other ways too. :

```
<div>Employee ID: [[_calculateId(index)]] Name: [[_calculateName(index)]]</div>
<button on-click="prev">Previous</button>
<button on-click="next">Next</button>on>

</template>
<script>
class MyTest extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-test'; }
      static get properties() { return { 
            index:{
               type:Number,
               value:0
            }
          }} 
                 // set this element's employees property
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.employees = [
                    { name: 'Bob', id: 'b1' },
                    { name: 'Ayesha', id: 'b2' },
                    { name: 'Fatma', id: 'b3' },
                    { name: 'Tony', id: 'b5' }
                ];
            }

           _calculateName(i) { return this.employees[i].name }
           _calculateId (i) { return this.employees[i].id }
            prev() {
                console.log("prev");
                if (this.index>0) { this.index -= 1 }

            }

            next() {
                console.log("next");
                if (this.index < this.employees.length-1){this.index +=1}

            }
 }
customElements.define(MyTest.is, MyTest);
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/gvYMQq)